# setting values of nested objects

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple `Ember.Object` that has an another `Ember.Object` as a member

```
TopObject = Ember.Object.extend({
    subObject: Ember.Object.extend({
        prop: ''
    })
});
```

The question is, can Ember set values of nested object if I create the object with loaded data like this:

```
TopObject.create({
    subObject: { prop: 'value'}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct that you need an object as a property of another object, use 
Ember.Object.create() for your subObject to create an instance. Now you can go out with your way as TopObject.create({subOject: {prop: 'value'}});

Here is a Little [fiddling](http://jsbin.com/oyurer/7/edit) on your objects